# Auto resizing controls on full screen in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, fullscreen, autoresize, dock

I want to auto resize my windows form controls on fullscreen. I use tableLayoutPanel and anchoring.

But it's not pleasing to the eyes. I used flowLayoutPanel, but it doesn't work. I  have around 35 controlrs on one single form, including labels, textboxes, comboboxex, radiobuttons, datagridview and checkbox.

Is there any other method by which I can resize the controls? And if not, can anybody suggest me a way to use the tableLayoutPanel and anchoring more effectively?

Comment: are you using Panels to house the necessary controls..? are you using your align properties properly.. can you provide a screen shot of the minimize form vs the full screen form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that what you want to use is the [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) property of all controls as well as using [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx). From the images you provided it looks like you want want the top half of the form to be a TableLayoutPanel, and to set the Dock Property to DockStyles.Fill. Then set the bottom ListView to DockStyles.Bottom.

You can either dock each control in a TableLayoutPanel cell or set the [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties to AnchorStyles.None to make the controls automatically be centered in the cells.

Comment: thanx @ademing2 i vl try the way u mentioned. As u see in the smapshots, some controls are big and some are small.. in that case what to do? Specially the controls which are in the Second row?

Comment: @PankajSinaiNagarsekar I would size them appropriately and then use the AnchorStyles.None technique that I outlined in my comment.